# ${M_{\mathscr{B}´}}^{\mathscr{B}}(id).$ real unitary proof understanding

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional space over $\mathbb{R}$, with a positive definite scalar product, and let $\{v_1...v_n\}=\mathscr{B}$ and $\{w_1...w_n\}=\mathscr{B}´$ be orthonormal bases of $V$. Show that the matrix ${M_{\mathscr{B}´}}^{\mathscr{B}}(id).$ is real unitary.[Hint:Use $\langle w_i,w_i\rangle=1$ and $\langle w_i,w_j\rangle=0$ if $I\neq j$, as well as the expression $w_i=\sum a_{ij}v_j$ for some $a_{ij}\in\mathbb{R}$. ]

SOLUTION.(a) We can write $v_i=\sum_\limits{j=1}^{n} a_{ij}w_j$. Then ${M_{\mathscr{B}´}}^{\mathscr{B}}(id)=(a_{ij})=A$. We contend that $A^tA=I$.If  $A^tA=(c_{ij})$,then

$(c_{ij})={}^iA^t.\:\:{}^jA=\sum_\limits{j=1}^{n}a_{ki}a_{kj}$.

But $\langle v_i,v_j\rangle=\sum_\limits{j=1}^{n}a_{ki}w_k,\sum_\limits{j=1}^{n}a_{pj}w_p=\sum_\limits{j=1}^{n}a_{ki}a_{kj}=c_{ij}$

thereby proving our contention. ***Solutions Manual for Lang´s Linear Algebra,Rami Shakarchi***.

I have drawn the following matrices to help my intuition and many more. If we associate $\{w_1...w_n\}=$ to each element in each vector column and row respectively we have the multiplication equals an identity matrix.

$A^tA=\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{21}&...&a_{i1}\\.&.&.&.\\.&.&.&.\\.&.&.&.\\a_{1j}&a_{2j}&...&a_{ij}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&...&a_{1j}\\a_{21}&...&a_{2j}\\.&.&.\\.&.&.\\.&.&.\\a_{i1}&...&a_{ij}\end{bmatrix}$

**Questions**:

**1)** Why write $\sum_\limits{j=1}^{n}a_{ki}a_{kj}$? Why use $k$?

**2)** Why does the author use $(c_{ij})={}^iA^t.\:\:{}^jA$? What does ${}^iA^t.\:\:{}^jA$? Column and row vectors? How is that on the matrix form?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your matrices $A^T$ and $A$ are not correct. For $A$, the element on the lower-left-hand corner should be $a_{n1}$ and the element on the lower-right-hand corner should be $a_{nn}$. The common notation $A=(a_{ij})$ is a way to tell the fact: The $(i,j)$-entry of the matrix $A$ is $a_{ij}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q.1 The author defined $C=A^{T}A$. Denote $C=(c_{ij})$ and $A^{T}=(a_{ij}^{'})$.
Note that $a'_{ij}=a_{ji}$. By the definition of matrix multiplication,
the $(i,j)$-entry of $C$ is given by 
$$
c_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a'_{ik}a_{kj}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{ki}a_{kj}.
$$
 Therefore, $k$ is just a dummy variable for writing summation.
There may be a typo in the book and you may need to double check it seriously. Reason: There is a $j$ on LHS but on RHS it becomes a dummy variable. On the other hand, there is no $k$ on LHS but $k$ appears on the RHS.

Q.2 The symbol $\sideset{^{j}}{}A$ denotes the $j-th$ column vector
of the matrix $A$ while the symbol $\sideset{^{i}}{}A^{t}$ denotes
the $i-th$ row vector of the matrix $A^{t}$. Therefore, $\sideset{^{i}}{}A^{t}.\sideset{^{j}}{}A$
denote the matrix multiplication of a $1\times n$ matrix to a $n\times1$
matrix and the outcome is a $1\times1$ matrix, which is identified
with a real number. In short, this symbol denotes the the multiplication
of the $i$-th row of $A^{t}$ by the $j$-th column of $A$. In my opinion, it is a poor choice of notation and I don't know why one denotes a row while the other one denotes a column. (You may need to ask the author.)